# Javascript: Regular expression for time format HH:MM

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I want to validate a string to check f it has valid time format. `HH:MM`
However,(due to some insane business reasons) I also want to validate `24:00` as correct.

The following works `{([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]}` but does not validate `24:00`.

Comment: it means that `00:00` would be an invalid time?

Comment: @zzlalani - Some companies uses a 30-hour system `00:00` to `29:59` :)

Comment: @Derek朕會功夫.. so they are using 25-hour and 1 second?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `2[0-3]` to `2[0-4]`:

```
^([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-4]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Or if you only want to include `24:00`:

```
^((([0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])|(24:00))$
```

Comment: With this expression, anything with 0x:00 won't work, for example: 01:00 or 09:00.

Comment: Not work with 01:00 etc. like said @Fortuna, i fixed this expression: `/^((([0-1]?[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9])|(24:00))$/`

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
 // Allows times like 24:05:00
  function validateTime(s) {
  var t = s.split(':');

  return /^\d\d:\d\d:\d\d$/.test(s) &&
     t[0] >= 0 && t[0] < 25 &&
     t[1] >= 0 && t[1] < 60 &&
     t[2] >= 0 && t[2] < 60;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this Regex:

```
/^(?:0\d|1[01]):[0-5]\d$/
```